# What exactly does "closure" refer to in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures, definition

I understand what closures are, but I am having some trouble grokking exactly what the term `closure` refers to.  I have seen the term used in many websites, but rarely do they agree on the actual definition of it.

- Is it the variables that are kept on the stack frame?
- Is it the function that is being returned?
- Is it the scope of the outer function?
- Is it the scope of the inner (returned) function?
- Is it maybe the **concept** of keeping the variables on the stack-frame after returning the function?

Can someone tell me exactly to what `closure` refers to?

Comment: +1 because you ask handy questions

Comment: After looking through 1/2 dozen explanations .. this one looks pretty good for breaking down the main considerations http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-closures-demystified/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From [JavaScript Closures](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml)

Two one-sentence summaries:

> A closure is the local variables for a
>   function - kept alive after the 
>   function has returned, or
>
> A closure is a stack-frame which is
>   not deallocated when the function
>   returns.  (as if a 'stack-frame' were
>   malloc'ed instead of being on the
>   stack!)

A very good article on closures

[Javascript Closures](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html)

> A "closure" is an expression
>   (typically a function) that can have
>   free variables together with an
>   environment that binds those variables
>   (that "closes" the expression).
>
> The simple explanation of a Closure is
>   that ECMAScript allows inner
>   functions; function definitions and
>   function expressions that are inside
>   the function bodies of other functions.
>   And that those inner functions are
>   allowed access to all of the local
>   variables, parameters and declared
>   inner functions within their outer
>   function(s). A closure is formed when
>   one of those inner functions is made
>   accessible outside of the function in
>   which it was contained, so that it may
>   be executed after the outer function
>   has returned. At which point it still
>   has access to the local variables,
>   parameters and inner function
>   declarations of its outer function.
>   Those local variables, parameter and
>   function declarations (initially) have
>   the values that they had when the
>   outer function returned and may be
>   interacted with by the inner function.

A good example over here

[JavaScript, time to grok closures](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/23/javascript-time-to-grok-closures.aspx)

Comment: I have written a set of articles on this with graphical explanations. Read chapters-4 and 5 here: https://rahuldotout.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/professional-javascript-part-4-scopes-and-scope-chain/

Comment: `A closure is the local variables for a function - kept alive after the function has returned, or` it should be variable only? or function? or both? because on the official document they said inner function as closure. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 6):

It's a function that "holds" a reference or references to something in another scope. For example:

```
var myArrayOfFunctions = [];

for(var i = 0; i<3: i++)
{
    //Note how the function being defined uses i, 
    //where i lives in the parent's scope, this creates a closure
    myArrayOfFunctions[i] = function(a) { return a + i;}    
}

myArrayOfFunctions[0](5);   //Prints 8 WTF!
myArrayOfFunctions[1](5);   //8 again
myArrayOfFunctions[2](5);   //Well, this 8 was expected
```

This happens because when the functions are "created", they do not copy the value of i, they hold a reference to i, so when we call the functions they use the current value of i which is 3.

[Here is a graphical explanation.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1482-A-Graphical-Explanation-Of-Javascript-Closures-In-A-jQuery-Context.htm)

Answer (score 4):

For me, the closures in JS allows you to do the following.
"a" remains available in the inner function when added to "b" although it is declared outside.

```
function adder(a){
  return function(b){
    return a + b;
  };
}
var add5 = adder(5);
alert( add5(10) );
```

For an extreme usage of JS closures, you can have a look at the [source code](http://github.com/pure/pure/blob/master/libs/pure.js) of the PURE library (a JS templating engine)

Comment: I know what closures are for, but your answer still doesn't really refine what the `closure` really refers to

Comment: I liked this example, as it is the smaller one I know to show what a closure is, and was the most revealing for me while learning functional JS.

Comment: Did you get this example from Stoyan Stefanov's JavaScript Patterns book?

Comment: @Dan, No. Why? It is exactly the same?

Comment: Yeah, very similar to the part on currying, but just coincidence I guess.

Comment: I saw the page 83... it is similar indeed. But the book was printed almost a year after this answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, a closure is a function defined within another function that outlives the parent function's scope. A common example is callbacks:

```
function delay_message(msg)
{
     setTimeout(function closure() { alert(msg); }, 1000);
}
```

In this case, the above `function closure` is defined within the body of `delay_message`, but the function definition -- as well as the parent function's variable `msg` -- outlive the scope of the `delay_message` function call.

Comment: so you're saying that the closure <i>is</i> the inner function ?

Comment: A "closure" is the combination of a function and its state. I.e., inner function that is bound to a set of local variables from the outer function.

Comment: The inner function (`function closure`) is created at parse time, but at that point there is no closure. A closure is created as `function delay_message` executes and binds its state to `function closure`.

Comment: An anonymous function is not a closure. Please do not keep spreading this misnomer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code that creates a closure with variables a and b

```
closure=(function(){ 

    var a=3
    var b=5 

return  function(operation){ 
          return operation(a,b)
      }
 }())


// The variables a and b are now part of the closure (They are retained even after the outer function returns)


closure(function(x,y){return x+y})  // outputs 8

closure(function(x,y){return x*y}) // outputs 15`
```

This particular closure can now take any function that operates on the variables a and b

Answer (score 1):

Essentially a closure is a function body closed over its identifiers (variables) within its local environment.

Answer (score 1):

A closure is a function value created from a nested function declaration or function  expression (i.e. lambda expression) whose body contains one or more references to variables declared in an outer (but not global) scope.

Answer (score 0):

Closure means a function(outer function) containing another function(inner function).

Closure is used to protect the data.

the use of closer is demostrated in the video link provide below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1s9PgtEoJs