# Why sometimes defining variable after calling the variable doesn't give undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have **two snippets,** why the **first one gives a value** while **the second gives undefined**?

**Snippet 1:**

```
function sayAlice() {
    var sayAlert = function() { alert(alice); }
    var alice = 'Hello Alice';
    return sayAlert;
}
var hi = sayAlice() ;
hi();//alert Hello Alice
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
alert(i); // alert undefined
var i = 1;
```

Comment: switch the lines in the second example and it works

Comment: yes...I know.I want to know why in the first snippet it worked

Comment: See the links I provided in my answer and you will learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in the second snippet, the variable 'i' is not defined in the moment of the alert is executed, but in the first snippet, what happens is that in the line

```
var sayAlert = function() { alert(alice); }
```

You are defining 'sayAlert' as a function, but this function is not executed in that moment. After that, you define the variable 'alice', and after that you return 'sayAlert', and in that moment, is when the alert is executed, and the variable 'alice' already has a value.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is this:

> Why sometimes defining variable after calling the variable doesn't
>   give undefined?

Then you provide this as example:

```
alert(i); // alert undefined
var i = 1;
```

It alerts `undefined` because you are issuing the `alert()` before `i` is defined.

And in the first example:

```
function sayAlice() {
    var sayAlert = function() { alert(alice); }
    var alice = 'Hello Alice';
    return sayAlert;
}
sayAlice()() //alert Hello Alice
```

The same behavior is to be expected, but it seems like your odd way of calling `sayAlice` happens twice with that `()()`. Which basically means while it might be happening quickly, but the first call to `sayAlice()` will set the `alice` variable, but the `alert` is most likely happening on the second iteration called via `sayAlice()()`.

Wait. Looking at it again, this is what is happening in the first example. This simply defines `sayAlert` as a function but does not actually run it:

```
var sayAlert = function() { alert(alice); }
```

But then you do this:

```
var alice = 'Hello Alice';
```

Which assigns a value to `alice`. And then you finally do this:

```
return sayAlert;
```

Which happens after the first two items. Meaning, at that third line you have a function defined, and then a variable defined, but it only comes together in the final line.

Which makes sense to me.  But `sayAlice()()` with the double `()` seems odd.

Comment: I have two snippets, the first doesn't give undefined while the second does

Comment: @JakeGould - It's not a puzzle. It's documented behavior of JS `closure`.

Answer (score 1):

All variable declarations are moved to the top of its scope by the javascript interpreter prior to running. This means that something like this:

```
function sayAlice() {
    var sayAlert = function() { alert(alice); }
    var alice = 'Hello Alice';
    return sayAlert;
}
sayAlice()() //alert Hello Alice
```

is equivalent to:

```
function sayAlice() {
    var sayAlert, alice;
    sayAlert = function() { alert(alice); }
    alice = 'Hello Alice';
    return sayAlert;
}
sayAlice()() //alert Hello Alice
```

When you call `sayAlice()()` it first resolves `sayAlice()` which returns you the function `sayAlert`, binded to the variable `alice` which has a value of 'Hello Alice'. As long as an inner function has access to an outer variable, that variable will retain its scope. So the line after assigning sayAlert i.e. `alice = 'Hello Alice'` modifies the variable referenced by the sayAlert function. So then at the point of invocation you get the expected result "Hello Alice".

Comment: I've modified my answer. The gist of it is no: the variable isn't assigned to the function. The function reads a reference to that variable which may have been changed elsewhere after the function has been declared.

Answer (score 1):

You have `inside` anonymous function that is a `closure`. Closures kinda bring their environment with them and can access local variables from it.

This [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) describes a case very similar to yours.

Also have a look at [What exactly does “closure” refer to in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801957/what-exactly-does-closure-refer-to-in-javascript) SO post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code and you will get an entirely different result...

```
function sayAlice() {
    var sayAlert = function() { alert(alice); }
    return sayAlert;
    var alice = 'Hello Alice';
}
```

Because `alice` is undefined when the function is called. In your example, `alice` is defined.