# why local variables in a function is not destroyed when the function pops on the stack

Tags: javascript

```
function Foo() {
   var num = 1;

   function Bar() {
      num++;
      console.log(num);
   }

   function Dummy() {
      Bar();
   }

   this.func = Dummy
}

let fooInstance = new Foo();
fooInstance.func();  // print 2
```

what I don't understand is:
after `new Foo()` is called, `function Foo()` get popped on the stack, any local variables created during `new Foo()` is called should be destroyed, then how come `fooInstance.func()` can still read something which has been already destroyed?

or does `function Foo()` not popped on the stack after `new Foo()` is called?

Comment: _"any local variables created during `new Foo()` is called should be destroyed"_... what makes you think that?

Comment: Not exactly duplicates but they help answer the question: [What exactly does "closure" refer to in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801957/what-exactly-does-closure-refer-to-in-javascript) [How are JavaScript closures garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798803/how-javascript-closures-are-garbage-collected)

Comment: @Phil isn't that how the stack works? https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-call-stack/ when a function (like `add` example in the link) finishes execution, it gets popped from from current stack, any local variable in that function also get destroyed

Comment: @Phil thanks for the clarification, just to confirm, does `var num` stored on the stack or the heap? also there is no way for `fooInstance` to access its  `var num` , that's why I thought it was just get destroyed when the constructor function finishes

Comment: @Phil No, this has nothing to do with `new`. The scope with the `var num` (and `Bar` and `Dummy`) lives as long as the `Bar` and `Dummy` functions live. Sure, `Dummy` is currently part of the `fooInstance`, but when you do `fooInstance.func = null` then the scope can be garbage-collected while the instance is not.

Comment: "*when a function […] gets popped from from current stack, any local variable in that function also get destroyed*" - no. Not in JavaScript. The variables persist as long as anything still references them. The tutorial that you linked doesn't even say anything about local variables! Read https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-closure/ instead.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your anwser, just to confirm, if `var num` still persist after `new Foo()` is called, what if there is another function to be called immediately after, then this new function will be on the stack, which can overwrite  `var num`?

Comment: @user22155685 No. The `var num` is not allocated on the stack. It's only referenced by the stack frame, not part of it. See the links Wing has shared above for details.

Comment: @Bergi  sorry, after reading the link, I am still confused, so does `var num` get allocated on the heap? because of new keyword, an instance is created on the heap, so as var num?

Comment: @user22155685 Javascript's stack is actually implemented in the C/C++ heap. It's the stack but the stack has been `malloc()` in C++. Don't confuse javascript's stack with C++ stack that javascript is implemented in. And the whole reason why javascript stack cannot be implemented as part of the C/C++ stack is precisely because of javascript's support of closures. See my answer to this question for a more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061856/javascript-cant-access-private-properties/26063201#26063201

Comment: FWIW this is true for all languages that support lexical closures: lisp, Haskell, Python, OCaml etc.